# how to use functions as arguments and apply to sublist in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

The question is pretty short.

Suppose `F` is any function, in this case I am using `F` = `length`, and `L` is any list that contains sublists, e.g. `L` in this case is `((3 3 3) (2 2) (1))`.
What should I do to have function `F` be applied to car of list `L`?

```
(defun try (F L)
    ('F (car L)))
```

When I call this function like

```
(try 'length '((3 3 3) (2 2) (1) (1) ))
```

I should get `3` as the result since the length of first Ssblist of `L`, `(3 3 3)`, is 3.

Comment: Here's the documentation on how to do it: http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_funcall.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `funcall`:

```
(funcall f (car l))
```